# Как спарсить жанр игры

Tags: html, python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, хочу спарсить жанр игры (метки) с этой страницы: https://store.steampowered.com/app/268540/The_Whispered_World_Special

Answer (score 3):

Используйте функцию `text` для тега, чтобы извлечь его содержимое:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = input('Вставьте ссылку на игру: ') 


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text


def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    shanr = soup.find('div', class_='glance_tags popular_tags').find_all('a', class_='app_tag')
    for w in shanr:
        print('<span>' + w.text.strip() + '</span><br />')


get_link(get_html(str(link) + '?l=russian'))
```

Comment: Ну тогда все еще проще, собираете требуемые теги вручную (пример обновлен)

Comment: Мое личное мнение: изучайте самостоятельно, забудьте про курсы (имеется ввиду платные). А где именно - решайте сами, благо с их поиском и выбором проблем нет